# How to get url of address bar in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to get the URL of current page from address bar and pass on to href of hyperlink.
Actually i am generating a dynamic url by passing the parameters with request. so if i use r

```
request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

it gives me only the name of servlet not the full url like

```
servlet?brand=optimum&price=20;
```

Is there any way to get complete url of address bar in jsp?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any other suggestions apart form this duplicate link..

Comment: By following your link i tried 
String yurl=  (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
But i showing a null value when i am writing it in a servlet.